How to replace a cell with another when updating UIColelctionView?
An error occurs when reloading a cell - "could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier CellContact.cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard".
The task is to change the CellSkeleton cell to a CellContact when the model is rebooted.
I can't understand the reason. All cells are registered.
My code:
/// I set the number of cells
    func getCellCount(section: Int) -> Int {
        if !modelForDisplay.isEmpty {
            return modelForDisplay.count
        }
        return 10
    }
/// This is register my cell - CellContact and CellSkeleton
    func registerCell(collectionView: UICollectionView) {
        if !modelForDisplay.isEmpty {
            collectionView.register(CellContact.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellContact.reuseIdentifier)
        }
        collectionView.register(CellSkeleton.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellSkeleton.reuseIdentifier)
    }

    func createCell(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if !modelForDisplay.isEmpty {
            return registerContactCell(collection: collectionView, indexPath: indexPath)
        }
        return registerSkeletonCell(collection: collectionView, indexPath: indexPath)
    }

/// My methods fillings cell
    private func registerContactCell(collection: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collection.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: CellContact.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath
        ) as? CellContact {
            let item = modelForDisplay[indexPath.item]
            cell.reloadData(title: item.name, imageData: item.imageData, phoneNumber: item.phones.maskPhone)
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    private func registerSkeletonCell(collection: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collection.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: CellSkeleton.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath
        ) as? CellSkeleton {
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
/// This reload UICollectionView

    func render(contactList: [ContactListDisplay]) {
        modelForDisplay = contactList
        collectionCardView.reloadData()
    }


You just need to register both cells at once.
func registerCell(collectionView: UICollectionView) {
   collectionView.register(CellSkeleton.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellSkeleton.reuseIdentifier)
   collectionView.register(CellContact.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellContact.reuseIdentifier)
}

Many thanks to Kirill Leonov for the answer.
